# have two files if column 1 of first file matchs with the column 1 value of other files add the values and write in new file

Tags: text-processing

File 1

```
Name    marks
sagat    20
raji     30
kamal    56
sanj     10
```

File 2

```
Name    marks
sagat    20
kamal    56
Jagan    30
suraj    90
sanj     78
```

Output file 1 (Common name)

```
Name    marks
sagat    40
kamal    112
sanj     88
```

Output file 2

```
Name    marks
raji     30
Jagan    30
suraj    90
```

Comment: Please put the description int the question instead of the title

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -- can you show us what you've tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a shell that supports process substitutions (like `bash`):

```
$ join <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 ) | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; print "Name", "Marks" } !/^Name/ { print $1, $2 + $3 }'
Name    Marks
kamal   112
sagat   40
sanj    88
```

The `join` command joins the two (sorted) files on the first column (the name) and outputs all names that occur in *both* files together with the marks from each file as the second and third column. This three-column data is fed into a short `awk` program that outputs the header and then simply prints the name and the sum of column two and three (avoiding processing any line that starts with `Name`, i.e. the old header).

```
$ join -v1 -v2 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 ) | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; print "Name", "Marks" } !/^Name/ { print $1, $2 + $3 }'
Name    Marks
Jagan   30
raji    30
suraj   90
```

This does a similar thing, but now the `join` outputs the names that are unique across both files, with the marks from that file as a second column.  The `awk` program is identical for simplicity, but the `$2 + $3` could be shortened to just `$2` here as there is no third column.

Related:

- My answer to the question [Find text not in both files using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552002/find-text-not-in-both-files-using-grep/552007#552007)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

I1=./InputFile1
I2=./InputFile2
O1=./OutputFile1
O2=./OutputFile2

rm $O1 $O2
awk 'NR>1{print $1" "$2}' $I1 | while read id mark
    do
        if grep "^$id[ \t]" $I2 >/dev/null; then
            add=`awk "/^$id[ \t]/{print \\$2}" $I2`
            echo $id $(expr $mark + $add) >>$O1
        fi
    done
(
    awk 'NR>1{print $1" "$2}' $I1
    awk 'NR>1{print $1" "$2}' $I2
) | sort -u | while read id mark
    do
        if ! grep "^id[ \t]" $O1 >/dev/null; then
            echo $id $mark >>$O2
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative `awk`

```
awk -v f="mark.txt" '{
    if (FNR==1) {nof+=1; printf ( "%s\t%s\n", $1, $2) > nof"."f}
        else {marks[$1]+=$2; howManyResults[$1]+=1}
    } END {for (name in marks) printf ("%s\t%s\n", name, marks[name]) >>howManyResults[name]"."f
}' file1 file2
```

Output

1.mark.txt

```
Name    marks
Jagan   30
suraj   90
raji    30
```

2.mark.txt

```
Name    marks
sanj    88
kamal   112
sagat   40
```

Answer (score 0):

Next a awk script that creates the mentioned output files

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f    
BEGIN        { OFS="\t";          }

NR==1        { print > "out1"; print > "out2" }
FNR==1       { next }
$1 in stud   { print $1,$2+stud[$1] > "out1"; delete stud[$1]; next }
NF == 2      { stud[$1]=$2;  next }

END          { for(i in stud) print i, stud[i] > "out2" }
```

And then:

```
$ chmod 755 procfs
$ procfs f1 f2
```