# Find text not in both files using grep

Tags: grep

I want to search two text files and print to a file the lines of each file that are only in one of the file.

For example, LIST-1.txt contains:

```
apples
dogs
paintings
mom
dad
don
```

LIST-2.txt contains

```
apples
don
dad
mom
cats
```

I want the output to be (in any order):

```
dogs
paintings
cats
```

I have tried this:

```
cat list-1.txt | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
   grep -v $line list-2.txt
done
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your loop is that in each iteration, you will get *all lines in the second file that is not the same as the current line in the first file*.

A variation of your loop is the concatenation of the output of the following two commands:

```
grep -v -xF -f LIST-1.txt LIST-2.txt
grep -v -xF -f LIST-2.txt LIST-1.txt
```

The first `grep` will get all lines from `LIST-2.txt` that does not correspond exactly to any line in `LIST-1.txt`, while the second `grep` does the same thing with the two files reversed.  This would actually give you the result that you mention in the question. (I see that [Jeff already mentioned this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552003/116858), so if you like this approach, go upvote his answer, not mine.)

It does require reading in one of the files into memory (as query strings), and would possible be considered slightly inelegant.  I also haven't really thought about under what circumstances it may fail to provide correct result.

Personally, I would go with

```
$ join -v 1 -v 2 <( sort LIST-1.txt ) <( sort LIST-2.txt )
cats
dogs
paintings
```

This performs a relational JOIN operation between the files.  Normally, this would return the entries that exists in both files (an inner join), but here we ask with `-v 1 -v 2` to see all entries that *don't* match up in either file.

The `join` utility requires sorted input (to be able to only hold one line from each file in memory at a time), which is why we sort both files and provide them to `join` via individual process substitutions.

In shells that do not have process substitutions, you may want to create sorted copies of the files before calling `join`:

```
sort -o LIST-1.txt.sorted LIST-1.txt &&
sort -o LIST-2.txt.sorted LIST-2.txt &&
join -v 1 -v 2 LIST-[12].txt.sorted
rm -f LIST-[12].txt.sorted
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it was just mentioned, but never explained explicitly: a GNU `comm` solution

```
comm --output-delimiter '' -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

`-3` suppresses lines that appear in both files, and the delimiter specification will just left-align the result. However the files need to be sorted for `comm` to be working.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you don't care about the results being re-sorted, one approach could be to:

1. `sort` the two files together
2. ask `uniq` to count the number of adjacent duplicates
3. ask `awk` to print only the lines that are not duplicated
4. ask `cut` to remove `uniq`'s counts

```
sort list-1.txt list-2.txt | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 1 { print}' | cut -c9-
```

To force grep to do it, you could run a whole-line, fixed-text, file-based exclusion in both directions:

```
{ grep -vxF -f list-1.txt list-2.txt; grep -vxF -f list-2.txt list-1.txt; }
```

This asks `grep` for the lines in the 2nd file that do not exist in the 1st file, where we reverse the filenames for the 2nd `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

if your input files have no duplicated entries individually, you can use:

```
sort list[12] |uniq -u
```

or use `awk` as an alternative:

```
awk '{ seen[$0]++ } END{ for (x in seen) if (seen[x]==1) print x }' list[12]
```

Comment: Note that the `uniq -u` solution would fail to find entries that are duplicated in one file but that do not exist in the other (but it's a neat solution if you can guarantee unique entries in each file individually).